# How to return keyboard for UITextField in UIAlertview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uialertview

I have one UIAlertView containing one UITextField with ok and cancel button. When I click on ok button i am calling webService. I want to return keyboard before calling webservice. Keyboard is not returning till response is not coming from webservice. Because of that half screen not visible to user during loading webservice. Here is my code which i did.

```
UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forgot Password" message:@"    " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    // Adds a username Field
    alertEmailtextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 29.0)]; 
    alertEmailtextfield.layer.cornerRadius = 07.0f;
    [alertEmailtextfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    alertEmailtextfield.placeholder = @"Enter Email";
    [alertEmailtextfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
    alertEmailtextfield.autocapitalizationType =UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; //For Making Caps Off
    [alertview addSubview:alertEmailtextfield];

[alertview show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        if ([alertEmailtextfield.text length] != 0) {

            if (![self validEmail:alertEmailtextfield.text]) {

                [AlertView UIAlertView:@"Enter email is not correct"];

            }else{
                //[alertEmailtextfield resignFirstResponder];

                [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startSpinner) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

                Boolean isForgotPassword = [serverConnection forgotPassword:alertEmailtextfield.text];

                if (isForgotPassword) {

                    NSLog(@"Mail is send");

                    [AlertView UIAlertView:@"New password is send to your mail"];
                    [spinner stopAnimating];

                }else{

                    [AlertView UIAlertView:@"User does not exist"];
                    [spinner stopAnimating];
                }
            }
        }else{

            [AlertView UIAlertView:@"Text Field should not be empty"];
        }
    }
}
```

Please if any one knows how to return keyboard in UIAlertView's UITextField, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be u are doing both task (webservice call and keyboard resinging) in same main thread so untill ur data is not loading from server keyboard is not resign from view. call weservice method in background thread like.

> -(void)alertView:(CustomAlert *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
>   {
>   [textField resignFirstResponder];
>   **UPdate**
>    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourWebservice) withObject:nil];
>
> }

Comment: When I am writting this method it giving error like for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'performSelectorInbackgroundThread'. If know Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: yes off course u are right. now i update my answer , plz check and reply soon

Answer (score 1):

Your UI is stuck waiting for your webservice to complete. Call your webservice in a background thread your problem will be solved.

```
[self performSelectorInbackgroundThread:@selector(yourWebservice)];
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to declare this method in .h?please help me.

Comment: When I am writting this method it giving error like for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'performSelectorInbackgroundThread'. If know Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @python. What i gave you is just a hint. It is not the exact syntax. The exact signature is ,     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourWebservice) withObject:nil];. It is available in NSThread.h